# VS Code Debug Console Double Spacing

Tags: visual-studio-code

As the title says, the debug console in VS Code is double-spacing for me.  I'm using the OSX edition.  Seems to work fine for others from what I've seen.  Have tried it with multiple programs and it always double spaces.

[image: VS Code Debug Console Double Spacing]

I can't seem to find any setting to change this behaviour.  Anyone able to help?

Thanks.

JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and testing I came to github where I filed a bug for this. It seems that it was known already under a different issue ID already, see  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17526 for details.